# Why doesn't annotation_raster work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the documentation, there's one example showing the usage of `annotation_raster` as below.

```
ggplot(aes(x=mpg, y=wt), data=mtcars) +
  annotation_raster('red', -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  geom_point()
```

This works fine, however, when I move the data and aes into the layer, suddenly it doesn't work anymore:

```
ggplot() +
  annotation_raster('red', -Inf, Inf, -Inf, Inf) +
  geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=wt), data=mtcars)  # doesn't work
```

This is perplexing because to me these two seem semantically identical.

Is there a reason why the second line won't work and is there a way to use `annotation_raster` without specifying data and aes early in the base layer?

Comment: it could probably be called a bug, but note that you can provide any dummy data in the base layer, `ggplot(data.frame(x=1,y=1), aes(x=x, y=y))` will do just as well. It's probably the strategy of training / stretching the scales that requires a real-data layer in a first step.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1164