# specifying x and y co-ordinates in annotate_custom in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I created a barchart in ggplot2 using the following code.

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
# Number of cars in each class:
g + geom_bar()
```

I created an image object using the code such as

```
img <- png::readPNG("./watermark.png")
rast <- grid::rasterGrob(img, interpolate = T)
```

Now I am trying to paste this image onto the plot using a command such as

```
g + annotation_custom(rast, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf,ymin=-Inf,ymax=Inf)
```

which creates the following plot
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdHBe.jpg

I understand that the x and y co-ordinates in annotation_custom are relative to the data plotted on the x and y axis.

In my case I have discrete data on the X Axis and want to paste this image in the top right corner, please can someone advise how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Although, not exactly the answer you are looking for, but do check these related answers, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633767/how-do-i-overlay-an-image-on-to-a-ggplot),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396095/why-doesnt-annotation-raster-work) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370977/annotation-raster-not-working-in-ggplot)

```
library(grid)
library(png)
mypngfile <- download.file('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Rlogo.png/200px-Rlogo.png', destfile = 'mypng.png', mode = 'wb')
mypng <- readPNG('mypng.png')
p + annotation_custom(rasterGrob(mypng))+
  geom_bar()
```

[image: image-in-plot]

Somehow, I cannot get `annotation_raster` to work with `geom_bar()`.