# how to achieve a hand-drawn pencil fill in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I came across this great blog post on visualizations: http://www.darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/visualizing-distributions-3
It includes a set of plots with an aesthetic that looks like hand-drawn pencil. Is there a way to get a textured fill like this in R, preferably using `ggplot2`? I know about the hand-drawn fonts and lines available in the [xkcd package](http://xkcd.r-forge.r-project.org/), but I'm particularly interested in getting the hand-drawn fill effect, as shown in the following histogram (taken from the darkhorseanalytics link posted above), which isn't available in the `xkcd` package.

[image: darkhorseanalytics pencil-fill histogram]

Any ideas on how to create something like that in R?

To be clear, I'm looking for ideas about how to generate a hand-drawn fill effect, similar to the [hand-drawn effect for lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/how-can-we-make-xkcd-style-graphs) that has been the subject of very productive brainstorming on this site. [Fill effects are not easy to implement in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2), but not impossible. Jittering a diagonal fill lines effect may be a reasonable place to start. Ben also mentioned `annotation_raster()` which would be another reasonable approach.

I know fill textures are not currently a priority for the ggplot2 development team, and they're [difficult to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901210/6859579) [for a number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206611/adding-custom-image-to-geom-polygon-fill-in-ggplot). That doesn't mean that they wouldn't be useful to have, or that we can't try to figure something out. :)

Comment: you might be able to cook something up with `annotation_raster` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633767/how-do-i-overlay-an-image-on-to-a-ggplot) ... ?

Comment: Related: [How to add Texture to fill colors in ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2). If it's for one time use, I'd opt for Excel and the likes, which allow for textures easily.

Comment: Thanks, @lukeA, I saw that question. It's a related issue, but the types of patterns used there don't approach the effect I'm looking for. I did wonder whether there would be a way to hack some of that material into a hand-drawn look, but I haven't made any progress with it. If you do, let me know!

Comment: No sorry, I dunno. I don't think that's what R is supposed to do, thus the lack of support for texture fills. As I said, I'd use Excel or an SVG editor to get a comic feel for graphics.

Comment: Take a look at: https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/