# R Pencil Style Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

There is any package that could give me plots output like pencil style?
Like this below? Not only for maps but also for statistical analysis? Histogram, scatterplot and so on?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [`ggrough`](https://xvrdm.github.io/ggrough/)

Comment: @markus amazing! The name of this chart style is rough?

Comment: Interesting question, but obviously violates rules against question for package recs. Perhaps you could rewrite it with a data example and a simpler task, such as requesting grid code to mask irregular shapes. The ggplot package uses grid for output.

Comment: @42 sorry I didnt understand. What rukes for packages recs? I ll edit it.

Comment: Questions that ask for package or software recs are considered off-topic on SO since they do not involve actual coding. Look at the off-topic dialog panel. You would need to post an example of code that created a data object and show what was not working.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41251319/how-to-achieve-a-hand-drawn-pencil-fill-in-ggplot2